Tool recommendation for cutting wood: 4"x6", 4"x12", 2"x12"
What tool is recommended for hobby/home use to cut through treated wood 4"x6"s, 4"x12"s, and 2"x12"s?
I'd also like to make 45-degree miter cuts and ideally, 30-degree and 60-degree cuts.  Or possibly at any arbitrary angle.
Is a 14" bladed chop saw the right tool?  I don't plan to cut any metal.  It will be a stationary tool - it doesn't need to be mobile or cordless.

FYI, brand recommendations are officially (and in practice, mostly, because there are certain exceptions at times) off-topic, particularly for general things like this. The type of tool - e.g., table saw vs. miter saw etc. is on-topic, but somewhat subjective. You may actually have better luck over at Woodworking Stack Exchange which is part of this network.

Hand saw and miter box will work. Handheld circular saw and angle guide can do it, a bit awkwardly  Miter saw will handle these cuts and is more portable than a table saw but less versatile; blade size depends on the largest piece you expect to cut and how much you want to spend. ... Really a matter of your budget, your preferences, and how many cuts you expect to make

@keshlam I wanted something more accurate and faster than a hand saw.  My handheld circular saw doesn't cut deep enough to go through a 4"x6".  Difference b/w a miter saw and a chop saw?

Handsaw can be as accurate as a power tool, and cuts common angles fine with a miter box ."Chop saw" generally means it cuts at 90 degrees only; miter adjusts and is calibrated for other angles.  Beyond that there are various sliding mechanism and blade size options depending on how large you need to cut. It's possible to cut a 4x6 with a handheld circular saw, with some skill or a straightedge clamped or tacked in place.

What about a beam saw? They are just bigger circular saws, but they can cut 6-by material in a single pass. It can do miters and most can do compound miters. Personally, I just use a standard circular saw and finish the cut by handsaw.

For the larger sizes, sliding miter saw may be a more efficient option than larger blade. Or may not.

To cut with standard 7-1/4" circular saw, simply make a pass, roll the board over and make another pass. That'll get you right through a 4"x with no problem.

Chain saw? See AwesomeFramers youtube

Most miter saws with 10” blades will cut 4x material at 90° in one pass. 45° probably; 60° no way. Check the specs on your shortlist of saws.
